# What results in the difference in these two segments of code

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am learning data structure and doing merge linklist exercise in python. But I meet some confusing problems. The definition of the node is:

```
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.next = None
```

In the following functions, parameter l1 and l2 are linklists to be merged, and the function should return a merged linklist.

The first implementation is as follow:

```
def merge(l1, l2):
    if l1 == None:
        return l2
    if l2 == None:
        return l1
    p = l1
    q = l2
    if l1.val < l2.val:
        l = l1
    else:
        l = l2
    start = l
    while p and q:
        if p.val < q.val:
            l.next = p
            p = p.next
        else:
            l.next = q
            q = q.next
        l = l.next
    if p!= None:
        l.next = p
    if q!=None:
        l.next = q
    return start
```

However this is not working because when it enters the loop, since  l1 becomes a infinite linkelist whose values are all 0. The next implementation did not cause this problem:

```
def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):
    if l1 == None:
        return l2
    if l2 == None:
        return l1
    l = ListNode(0)
    start = l
    while l1 and l2:
        if l1.val < l2.val:
            l.next = l1
            l1 = l1.next
        else:
            l.next = l2
            l2 = l2.next
        l = l.next
    if l1!= None:
        l.next = l1
    if l2!=None:
        l.next = l2
    return start.next
```

What results in the difference between these two segments? How come l1 becomes an infinite linklist? 
And I also have another question: variable 'l' was assigned to 'start' at the beginning, in each loop, l moves to the next node, while start does not have any modification. Why start is pointing to a merged list at the end? Why not remain the same or just equals to l?

I hope someone can answer my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: What are l1 and l2? You call them lists, but they appear to have `val` and `next` methods; what do those do?

Comment: @DanielRoseman They are linklists to be merged. I just added the definition of the node to make it more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `l1.val < l2.val`, so `l = l1`. Since `p = l1` and `q = l2` then `p.val < q.val`, so then `l.next = p`. That means `l.next` is `l1` which is `l`. The node is pointing to itself. By starting with a fresh node `l = ListNode(0)` in the second implementation you avoid this self reference.

Comment: Then why the variable 'start' changes at the end of the second algorithm? Since it points to l at the beginning, shouldn't it have same value as l?

Comment: No because you changed `l` to something else.